# How to set antenna gain in Veins-5.x?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I want to implement the formula for Free Space Propagation Model. However, I don't know how to set or get the gain for the transmitter and receiver. Should I just consider it unity? In veins-5.2 the only available antenna parameters are:

```
*.**.phy80211p.antenna =

*.**.phy80211p.antennaOffsetX =
 
*.**.phy80211p.antennaOffsetY =
 
*.**.phy80211p.antennaOffsetZ =
 
*.**.phy80211p.antennaOffsetYaw =
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of your question only indicate the position offset in terms of the X, Y, and Z location.

The gain is set with the radiation pattern given in the `antenna.xml` file. The [Veins HowTo](https://veins.car2x.org/documentation/modules/#antennas) provides a few information regarding this.

Comment: the SampledAntenna1D has a getGain() function, but I don't know how to access it from my application .cc file.